# Hibernate HQL issue expecting IDENT found "*"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need get all data from relative table so I'm using something like this (i would use it in sql)

```
    private static final String SELECT_OOPR_TO_SEND = "SELECT R.* " +
                                                      "FROM offerOrderProjectRel R, offerOrder O, project P " +
                                                      "WHERE P.id = R.project_id and O.id = R.offer_order_id " +
                                                      "and O.type = 'ORDER' and (P.status = 'PENDING' or P.status ='PROTECTED')" ;
; 
    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<OfferOrderProjectRel> findAllOfferOrderToSendToSalesmans() {
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(SELECT_OOPR_TO_SEND);
        List<OfferOrderProjectRel> list = q.list();
        return list;
    }
```

After lauching this code i'm getting that error :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT,
> found '**' near line 1, column 10 [SELECT R.* FROM offerOrderProjectRel
> R, offerOrder O, project P WHERE P.id = R.project_id and O.id =
> R.offer_order_id and O.type = 'ORDER' and (P.status = 'PENDING' or
> P.status ='PROTECTED')]

So how can I obtain all data from column R with hibernate?

Comment: Have you tried just R instead of R.*?

Comment: edit the query to "select R from". Omit R.* This is HQL syntax.

Comment: HQL works with entities, fields and associations. Never with tables and columns. It's not the same thing as SQL. If it was, it would be named SQL. Read the Hibernate documentation.

Comment: thank you guys, yeah i have to read documentation, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The method [`createQuery`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29) expects an HQL query string.

HQL is an [object-oriented querying language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html).

HQL interprets `SELECT R.*` as select the member field `*` of the object `R`.

But `*` is not a member field of `R`. Is it?..

To select all the member fields of `R` use:

```sql
SELECT R
FROM offerOrderProjectRel R, offerOrder O, project P
WHERE P.id = R.project_id and O.id = R.offer_order_id
and O.type = 'ORDER' and (P.status = 'PENDING' or P.status ='PROTECTED')
```

Answer (score 8):

you use SQL query, not hql query, so it should be

```
Query q = getSession().createSQLQuery(SELECT_OOPR_TO_SEND);
```

Comment: When i use EntityManager, how do i use getSession()?

Comment: you don't use getSession(). you need SessionFactory not EntityManager

Answer (score 5):

For people that received the "expecting IDENT found “*”" error when using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` and found this question I'll add that you can change the `nativeQuery` flag to `true`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> myFindAll();
```